# Sinatra app.post gives a 403

Tags: sinatra

I'm trying to get the simple put and get running. Get works perfectly but I seem to get a 404 with a PUT.

Things I've tried:

1. Wrote up code for a app.get "/users/:id" and localhost:3000/users/400 to print the user's id on the browser -> this works and it's a get
2. Tried doing the same for a post -> app.post "/users/add" (code below) and did a "localhost:3000/users/add/11" but I get a 404.

My doubts:

1. How can I test the post on a browser? How should the URL be? Where can I put info to be posted in the URL? Or should it not be specified in the URL? (This is confusing) I am guessing the lack of input data is giving me a 404.

I run this on the Sinatra framework and this what I see on the console:

> INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=10137 port=3000
>   ::1 - - [19/Mar/2015:11:36:34 -0700] "GET /users/add HTTP/1.1" 403 - 0.0156

(Wait, shouldn't this be a POST??)

> ::1 - - [19/Mar/2015:11:36:45 -0700] "GET /users/add/11 HTTP/1.1" 404 688 0.0086

(My question on how I specify the data to be put)

> ::1 - - [19/Mar/2015:11:43:15 -0700] "GET /users/add/name=11 HTTP/1.1" 404 693 0.0018

My routes users.rb code:

```
module Routes
  module Users
    def self.registered(app)
      app.post '/users/add' do
         reqUserId = params[:id]
         "params id #{reqUserId}"
    end  
 end
end
```

Any help would be great. I'm super open to reading anything too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like you got confused by a few things here.

First of all, put and post are not the same. [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest) Probably you want use post.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
get "/users/add" do
    erb :useradd
end

post "/users/add" do
    params[:userId]
    #render layout or redirect to a url
end
```

And your `useradd` erb template would look like this:

```
<form action="/users/add" method="post">
    <input name="userId" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

So your browser does a GET if you open a url like `/users/add` which renders your view. And if you press on `submit` the form with your input fields gets posted.

To test your Post routes you can also use something like curl:

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://localhost:3000/users/add
```